# SQL - How do I backup a database by clicking one button?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hello stackoverflow user

I have an SQL database that i want to be able to backup it in a click of a button (don't ask why)so how d i do that

Comment: Which part of this is your question about? Creating the page with the button? Post the a form? Connecting to the database? Making the backup? Show us what you have so far and where you're stuck. In its current form, this question is _way_ too broad for SO.

Comment: Also, please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: thank you for the example but i just started coding and i want to know how to create a code that back ups my database

Answer (score 0):

Very Simple.

Just create a new PHP web page say `backup.php` and make a form (with the field of the database name) and a submit button on it.
When it clicked, you redirect to another temporary page say `saving.php`

In that page:

```
<?php
   $dbhost = 'localhost:3036';
   $dbuser = 'root';
   $dbpass = 'password';

   $dbname = $_POST['database_name'];

   $backup = $dbname . date("Y-m-d-H-i-s") . '.gz';
   $command = "mysqldump --opt -h $dbhost -u $dbuser -p $dbpass ". "test_db | gzip > $backup";

   system($command);
?>
```

After the database is backed up, so redirect back to `backup.php`

Every time you clicked that button, your database is backed up in your desired location

Comment: `mysqldump –e –u[username] -p[password] -h[hostname] [database name] > C:\this\is\path\to]file\[filename].sql`

Comment: Command in above answer is for linux, and in comment is for windows.
I hope you will have an idea by looking windows command how to give location path in linux too.

Comment: This file will store in the path specified.

Comment: dosen't work... just outputs an empty sql file BTW do i need to write the [] or it's just to show where to put them

Comment: You must remove the space between `-p` and the password. From the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_password): _"If you use the short option form (-p), you cannot have a space between the option and the password."_ That goes for both linux and windows.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a linux server the following code saves a file for each day of the 31 days of a month each time you run it. For windows server it may need some mods.

Create a form that directs to this page:

```
    <?php


define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_NAME', 'your_database_name');
define('DB_USER', 'your_database_username');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'your_username_password');
define('BACKUP_SAVE_TO', 'backup_storage_path'); 

$time = time();
$day = date('j', $time);
if ($day == 1) {
    $date = date('Y-m-d', $time);
} else {
    $date = $day;
}

$backupFile = BACKUP_SAVE_TO . '/' . DB_NAME . '_' . $date . '.gz';
if (file_exists($backupFile)) {
    unlink($backupFile);
}
$command = 'mysqldump --opt -h ' . DB_HOST . ' -u ' . DB_USER . ' -p\'' . DB_PASSWORD . '\' ' . DB_NAME . ' | gzip > ' . $backupFile;
system($command);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

im not sure about your current code or what SQL module are you using. For now, ill assume you're using the built in sqlite 3 module. In that case i still need to know what you mean by backup. Is it to save info inputted by the user on the database, or do you mean do copy the data in a database into another one as backup? The question is unclear, but ill assume its the second.
1. ) First import Tkinter and sqlite 3

```
import Tkinter, sqlite3
```

2.) Then connect to the file where your databse is stored, and create a cursor

```
conn = sqlite3.connect("table.db")
c = conn.cursor()
```

3.) Next create the Tkinter object(button in this case)  and create a def for its callback

```
master = Tk()

def callback():
   c.execute("SELECT * FROM table_name")
   Data = c.fetchall()
   c.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table_backup
         (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, some_row, some_row2)''')

   row_1 = Data[0]
   row_2 = Data[1]
   c.execute("INSERT INTO table_backup(some_row, some_row2) VALUES(?, ?);",   (row_1, row_2))
   conn.commit()
b = Button(master, text="OK", command=callback())
b.pack()

mainloop()
```

Comment: That's the strangest PHP-code (since that's what the question was tagged with) I've seen.

Comment: You're right, i didnt see the tag. thats sqlite 3. I dont have any experience with PHP so sorry. Forget it :)

Comment: Not many rights here. Python instead of PHP. SQLite3 instead of Mysql (which also is one of the tags). :-).

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can press the `Export` tab when selecting on you database in phpmyadmin. Then choose your preferences and press `Go`.